# Accessing private instances of classes from another class

Tags: c++, private-members

I'm a scholar for Computer Games Programming, currently studying C++. I'm trying to access a private Texture2D and Vector 2 type in a .h file from a .cpp file in order to give an object position and image.

This is the Player.cpp file

```
#include "Player.h"
#include <sstream>


Player::Player(int argc, char* argv[]) : Game(argc, argv), _cPlayerSpeed(0.1f), _cPlayerFrameTime(250)
{
    //Player Inits
_playerDirection;
_playerFrame = 0;
_playerCurrentFrameTime = 0;
_playerSpeedMultiplier = 1.0f;

//Init of Important Game Aspects
Graphics::Initialise(argc, argv, this, 1024, 768, false, 25, 25, "Genocide: Remastered", 60);
Input::Initialise();
Graphics::StartGameLoop(); //Start of Game Loop, calls Update and Draw in game loop.
}


Player::~Player()
{
}

void Player::Input(int elapsedTime, Input::KeyboardState* state)
{
    // Checks for directional keys pressed
    if (state->IsKeyDown(Input::Keys::D))
    {
        _playerPosition->X += _cPlayerSpeed * elapsedTime;
    }

}



/// <summary> All content should be loaded in this method. </summary>
void Player::LoadContent()
{
    _playerPosition = new Vector2();
    _playerTexture = new Texture2D();
    _playerTexture->Load(" ", false);
    _playerSourceRect = new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, 0, 0);
}

/// <summary> Called every frame - update game logic here. </summary>
void Player::Update(int elapsedTime)
{

}

/// <summary> Called every frame - draw game here. </summary>
void Player::Draw(int elapsedTime) 
{

}
```

This is the Player.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef WIN32 
    #ifndef _DEBUG
        #pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:windows /ENTRY:mainCRTStartup")
    #endif
#endif

#include "S2D/S2D.h"
using namespace S2D;

class Player : public Game
{
public:
    Player(int argc, char* argv[]);
    ~Player();
    /// <summary> All content should be loaded in this method. </summary>
    void virtual LoadContent();

    /// <summary> Called every frame - update game logic here. </summary>
    void virtual Update(int elapsedTime);

    /// <summary> Called every frame - draw game here. </summary>
    void virtual Draw(int elapsedTime);

private:
    Vector2* _playerPostion;
    Rect* _playerSourceRect;
    Texture2D* _pacmanTexture;
    const float _cPlayerSpeed;
    const int _cPlayerFrameTime;

    int _playerDirection;
    int _playerFrame;
    int _playerCurrentFrameTime;
    float _playerSpeedMultiplier;

    void Input(int elapsedTime, Input::KeyboardState* state);
    void CheckPaused(Input::KeyboardState* state, Input::Keys pauseKey);
    void CheckViewportCollision();  
    void UpdatePlayer();
};
```

I've literally copied and pasted something I've been working on with my Lecturer and changed variable, type and instantiation declaration and his works. Curious as to why mine isn't. Help will be much appreciated.

Many thanks,

Ryan.

Comment: '_playerPosition': undeclared identifier, same with '_playerTexture'

Comment: Take care using `_lowercase`. `_UPPERCASE` is reserved in C++ as is `_lowercase` if used at file scope. You're ok at the moment, just take care.

Comment: Add `friend B;` inside `class A {}` if you want to give class A permission to access private properties and methods inside class B. You may also want to consider giving permission only to specific methods. It was long time I was dealing with C++ but I think I am nto far from it :)

Comment: These are the same class, `Player`, not different ones.

Comment: Well, the title says "...from another class". I've noticed now after reading again the text this is the same class. Sorry my bad.

Comment: Yeah, my mistake guys, I made a booboo saying that Player.h and Player.cpp are different classes :-))

Answer (score 4):

In the header, your `Texture2D*` is called `_pacmanTexture`, whereas in your implementation, you've called it `_playerTexture`. Similarly, you've misspelled `_playerPosition` in the header.

Answer (score -1):

Usual way to give access to private resources of a class to another class is to add public accessor methods (getter, setter).